# jquery ui resizable resizing to left issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

when I resize the jquery ui resizable element on left side it unexpectedly changes its width.

here's codepen: `[CodePen](https://codepen.io/nitinjs-the-typescripter/pen/KxGOqX)`

According to this ticket on jquery ui forums this issue is marked as not fixable (6 years ago)
https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9017
I wonder if any workaround available?

Also the resizable stops working when I remove the jquery UI css, how do I use it without jquery ui css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position: relative; display: block;` to your `.tsContainer>.panel` and it's working just fine. Try it out.

You can also set `height: 100% !important; max-width: 100%` for `.ui-resizable` element so it's not changing it's height while resizing.

You can also add

```
$time_scroller.draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    containment: "#pnlScrollbarContainer",
    drag: function(e, ui) {
        if(ui.position.left < 0)
            ui.position.left = 0;
    }
});
```

So it's not jumping outside of the box

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yxQBOG